# Why Flutter icons man and woman don't work?

Tags: flutter

Icons.man and Icons.woman seem not to work, neither in Android Studio icon preview bar on the left nor in the app. Am I doing anything wrong?

For instance, Icons.male and Icons.female work.

Comment: They aren't shown on my preview bar as well, but work just fine in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "flutter upgrade" in console window resolved the issue